# Magento 2 cron scheduled but not executing for sales email

Tags: magento-2.1, cron

I have a store in Magento 2.1.7. My emails were working fine a few days ago but suddenly it stops working. I also noticed my config fields in the admin panel are also not editable anymore and I'm not able to change copyright text as well. I don't know what happened.

I checked the database and found cron jobs are being scheduled but not executing. How to fix this issue?

[image: Cron job screenshot]

Here is my config.php file. It includes only modules section. But still admin configurations are still locked.

```
<?php
return array (
  'modules' => 
  array (
    'ATZEN_CheckoutPayment' => 1,
    'Magento_Store' => 1,
    'Goivvy_DJS' => 1,
    'Magento_AdminNotification' => 1,
    'Magento_Eav' => 1,
    'Magento_Directory' => 1,
    'Magento_Customer' => 1,
    'Magento_Indexer' => 1,
    'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport' => 1,
    'Magento_Backend' => 1,
    'Magento_Theme' => 1,
    'Magento_Authorization' => 1,
    'Magento_Backup' => 1,
    'Magento_Cms' => 1,
    'Magento_Catalog' => 1,
    'Magento_BundleImportExport' => 1,
    'Magento_Search' => 1,
    'Magento_CacheInvalidate' => 1,
    'Magento_Payment' => 1,
    'Magento_Config' => 1,
    'Magento_CatalogImportExport' => 1,
    'Magento_Quote' => 1,
    'Magento_Rule' => 1,
    'Magento_Msrp' => 1,
    'Magento_SalesSequence' => 1,
    'Magento_Sales' => 1,
    'Magento_CatalogInventory' => 1,
    'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite' => 1,
    'Magento_Widget' => 1,
    'Magento_Checkout' => 1,
    'Magento_CheckoutAgreements' => 1,
    'Magento_Newsletter' => 1,
    'Magento_Downloadable' => 1,
    'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite' => 1,
    'Itoris_Core' => 1,
    'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport' => 1,
    'Magento_SampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_ConfigurableProduct' => 1,
    'Magento_Contact' => 1,
    'Magento_Cookie' => 1,
    'Magento_Cron' => 1,
    'Magento_CurrencySymbol' => 1,
    'Magento_Vault' => 1,
    'Magento_CustomerImportExport' => 1,
    'Magento_CustomerSampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_Deploy' => 1,
    'Magento_Developer' => 1,
    'Magento_Dhl' => 1,
    'Magefan_Blog' => 1,
    'Magento_CatalogRule' => 1,
    'Magento_ImportExport' => 1,
    'Magento_CatalogSearch' => 1,
    'Magento_CatalogWidget' => 1,
    'Magento_Email' => 1,
    'Magento_User' => 1,
    'Magento_Fedex' => 1,
    'Magento_GiftMessage' => 1,
    'Magento_GoogleAdwords' => 1,
    'Magento_GoogleAnalytics' => 1,
    'Magento_Ui' => 1,
    'Magento_GroupedImportExport' => 1,
    'Magento_GroupedProduct' => 1,
    'Magento_Tax' => 1,
    'Magento_DownloadableImportExport' => 1,
    'Magento_Captcha' => 1,
    'Magento_Security' => 1,
    'Magento_LayeredNavigation' => 1,
    'Magento_Marketplace' => 1,
    'Magento_MediaStorage' => 1,
    'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable' => 1,
    'Magento_MsrpSampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_Multishipping' => 1,
    'Magento_NewRelicReporting' => 1,
    'Ebizmarts_MailChimp' => 1,
    'Magento_OfflinePayments' => 1,
    'Magento_SalesRule' => 1,
    'Magento_OfflineShipping' => 1,
    'Magento_PageCache' => 1,
    'J2t_Autoadd' => 1,
    'Magento_Paypal' => 1,
    'Magento_Persistent' => 1,
    'Magento_ProductAlert' => 1,
    'Magento_Weee' => 1,
    'Magento_ProductVideo' => 1,
    'Magento_Bundle' => 1,
    'Magento_Reports' => 1,
    'Magento_RequireJs' => 1,
    'Magento_Review' => 1,
    'Magento_CatalogSampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_Rss' => 1,
    'Magento_BundleSampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_DownloadableSampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_SalesInventory' => 1,
    'Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_ConfigurableSampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_SalesSampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_ThemeSampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_ReviewSampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_GroupedProductSampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_Integration' => 1,
    'Magento_SendFriend' => 1,
    'Magento_Shipping' => 1,
    'Magento_Sitemap' => 1,
    'Magento_Authorizenet' => 1,
    'Magento_Swagger' => 1,
    'Magento_Swatches' => 1,
    'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation' => 1,
    'Magento_SwatchesSampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_CatalogRuleSampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_TaxImportExport' => 1,
    'Magento_TaxSampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_ProductLinksSampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_CmsSampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_Translation' => 1,
    'Magento_GoogleOptimizer' => 1,
    'Magento_Ups' => 1,
    'Magento_UrlRewrite' => 1,
    'Magento_EncryptionKey' => 1,
    'Magento_Usps' => 1,
    'Magento_Variable' => 1,
    'Magento_Braintree' => 1,
    'Magento_Version' => 1,
    'Magento_Webapi' => 1,
    'Magento_WebapiSecurity' => 1,
    'Magento_SalesRuleSampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_Wishlist' => 1,
    'Magento_WidgetSampleData' => 1,
    'Itoris_CatalogPermissions' => 1,
    'Magento_WishlistSampleData' => 1,
    'Mageplaza_Core' => 1,
    'Mageplaza_Affiliate' => 1,
    'Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation' => 1,
    'Mageside_ShippingMatrixRates' => 1,
    'QualityUnit_PostAffiliatePro' => 1,
    'Smartwave_Core' => 1,
    'Smartwave_Filterproducts' => 1,
    'Smartwave_Megamenu' => 1,
    'Smartwave_Porto' => 1,
    'Smartwave_Socialfeeds' => 1,
    'Solwin_Instagram' => 1,
    'VenSoc_Customtab' => 1,
    'WebShopApps_MatrixRate' => 1,
    'WeltPixel_Backend' => 1,
    'WeltPixel_Quickview' => 1,
    'Xtento_XtCore' => 1,
    'Xtento_OrderExport' => 1,
    'Yosto_AddressAttribute' => 1,
    'Yosto_AttributeRelation' => 1,
    'Yosto_CustomerAddress' => 1,
    'Yosto_CustomerAttribute' => 1,
    'Yosto_OrderAttribute' => 1,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think the fact that you cannot edit the values in admin panel are a consequence of having the configurations overwritten in the files **config.php and/ or env.php**. This happens when you set configurations via CLI the command with the **--lock** option:

```sh
bin/magento config:set [--scope="..."] [--scope-code="..."] [-l | --lock] path value
```

This also happens **when you dump the config** and the **env.php and config.php** get populated. The command used is:

```sh
bin/magento app:config:dump
```

In order to unlock the configuration and make it available for admin editing, you need to remove from the configuration files the entries which refer to your admin configuration paths.

2. As for the crons execution, please check if you have errors in the **cron.log and/or exception.log**. Maybe there is something going on and stopping the cron schedule from running properly.

---

***LE:*** after discussions, it was identified that several magento default sample files were missing from the project root folder. upon restoring, the crons started to work properly.

Comment: Thanks for reply Diana. I checked logs and found this under update.php: update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:  /chroot/home/atzeninf/atzen.info/html/nginx.conf.sample  /chroot/home/atzeninf/atzen.info/html/.travis.yml  /chroot/home/atzeninf/atzen.info/html/.php_cs  /chroot/home/atzeninf/atzen.info/html/Gruntfile.js.sample  /chroot/home/atzeninf/atzen.info/html/package.json.sample  /chroot/home/atzeninf/atzen.info/html/php.ini.sample  /chroot/home/atzeninf/atzen.info/html/.htaccess.sample  /chroot/home/atzeninf/atzen.info/html/.user.ini [] []

Comment: is it possible that these files were removed? do they exist in your project installation?

Comment: I checked, these files are not exist in the project installation.

Comment: ok, those are files which come from the default Magento installation. Is there any way you can retrieve them back? otherwise, redownload them from a clean 2.1.7 install or from https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases/tag/2.1.7. Worst case scenario, create empty files with that particular naming and give it  a try *(but this is not a clean solution).*

Comment: I have retrieved these files from installation and moved to server. Now there is no any error in update.php file.

Comment: did the crons start to work again, also?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120283/discussion-between-diana-botean-and-feroze-ahmed).